# Javascript keypress to make ligh

Tags: javascript

on a web page how do you enable the user to light up the boxes/items on the page using a specific key on your keyboard? eg. i want M to light up my title and when i press M again it turns it off?

this is what i have so far but feel like it could be cleaned up a lot

```
$('#abutton').click(function() {
    $('#abutton').removeClass('off').addClass('on');
    $('#bbutton').removeClass('on').addClass('off');
    $('#cbutton').removeClass('on').addClass('off');
    $('#dbutton').removeClass('on').addClass('off');
    window.scrollTo(0,0);
});

$('#bbutton').click(function() {
    $('#abutton').removeClass('on').addClass('off');
    $('#bbutton').removeClass('off').addClass('on');
    $('#cbutton').removeClass('on').addClass('off');
    $('#dbutton').removeClass('on').addClass('off');
    window.scrollTo(0,0);
});

$('#cbutton').click(function() {
    $('#abutton').removeClass('on').addClass('off');
    $('#bbutton').removeClass('on').addClass('off');
    $('#cbutton').removeClass('off').addClass('on');
    $('#dbutton').removeClass('on').addClass('off');
    window.scrollTo(0,0);
});

$('#dbutton').click(function() {
    $('#abutton').removeClass('on').addClass('off');
    $('#bbutton').removeClass('on').addClass('off');
    $('#cbutton').removeClass('on').addClass('off');
    $('#dbutton').removeClass('off').addClass('on');
    window.scrollTo(0,0);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add the general class `.button` to all of them. Then remove `on` from all `.button` elements and add `on` class to exact clicked element.

```
$('.button').click(function() {
    $('.button').removeClass('on').addClass('off');
    $(this).removeClass('off').addClass('on');
    window.scrollTo(0,0);
});
```

Comment: do if i wanted to start afresh, what do i put into my HTML and which goes into my javascript section?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add addEventListener to your code and check inside it if the pressed key has keyCode you're expecting to do some action. Look on example below:

`addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
    if (event.keyCode === '13')
      //light on/off
  });`

Please check [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keydown) for more details

EDIT: [jQuery also has its keyboard events](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/keyboard-events/)